# ggplot2 plotting single data frame with 10 different levels

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using R studio
I have a single data frame with three columns titled

```
colnames(result)
[1] "v"      "v2"     "Lambda"
```

I wish to use ggplot2 to create an overlay plot assigning 10 different colors to each of the 10 different values in the Lambda column

```
summary(result$Lambda)
  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10 
101 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100
```

Now I created a factor for the Lambda values as follows:

```
result$Lambda<-factor(result$Lambda, levels=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10), labels=c("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"))

qplot(x=v, y=v2, data=result, geom="line", fill=Lambda main="Newton Revolved Plot", xlab="x=((L/2)*((1/t)+2*t+t^(3)))", ylab="y=(L/2)*(log(1/t)+t^(2)+(3/4)*t^(4))-(7*L/8)")
```

but this command does not work.

I am just inquiring about how to plot 10 different plots, one plot for each Lambda value.  Or perhaps resources for the novice..

Thank you in advance

```
2.000000e+00 0.000000e+00      1
3    6.250000e+00 6.778426e+00      1
4    1.666667e+01 3.345069e+01      1
5    3.612500e+01 1.024319e+02      1
6    6.760000e+01 2.451953e+02      1
7    1.140833e+02 5.022291e+02      1
8    1.785714e+02 9.230270e+02      1
9    2.640625e+02 1.566085e+03      1
10   3.735556e+02 2.498901e+03      1
105  7.225000e+01 2.048637e+02      2
106  1.352000e+02 4.903906e+02      2
107  2.281667e+02 1.004458e+03      2
108  3.571429e+02 1.846054e+03      2
109  5.281250e+02 3.132171e+03      2
110  7.471111e+02 4.997803e+03      2
111  1.020100e+03 7.595947e+03      2
112  1.353091e+03 1.109760e+04      2
250  1.766205e+05 6.488994e+06      3
251  1.876500e+05 7.034992e+06      3
252  1.991295e+05 7.614744e+06      3
253  2.110680e+05 8.229615e+06      3
254  2.234745e+05 8.880996e+06      3
255  2.363580e+05 9.570303e+06      3
```

Here is some sample date,  the first column is the "v", the second column is "v2"  and the third column is the "Lambda" column.  (not include the 0th column as the index)

Just to rephrase my R problems,  I have a single data frame with 10 levels each with 100 entries (roughly.. see above for exact count).  and wish to use ggplot2 to plot each level a different color.
there are two ways I can think of
1) Find the correct ggplot2 option and distinguish each level
2) split this single data frame titled "result" into 10 subsets.

thank you very much in advance.

Comment: What goes wrong in your attempt?

Answer (score 1):

for a line use

```
color=
```

instead of

```
fill=
```

But without any data to reproduce it is hard to know if that is what you want.